# How to create an efficient objects activation and deactivation system to progress the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a personal project which is an action adventure puzzle game. Basically, there are levels with puzzles involved to challenge the player.

Assume that Level 1 has two stages of puzzles: **(Stage 1) Puzzle A, B and C with Clue A, B and C provided.** **(Stage 2) Puzzle D, E and F with Clue D, E and F provided.**

If the respective puzzle is completed, the respective clue will be deactivated, such as Puzzle A has completed, Clue A will be deactivated. Vice versa.

If all Stage 1 puzzles has completed, all Stage 1 puzzles will be deactivated and all Stage 2 puzzles will be activated.

I have tried by hard-coding them. If using array class is a must, is there any way to reduce the redundancy? If not using array class, is there a better way to code?

```
public class Item
{
    public GameObject[] puzzle;
    public GameObject[] clue;
    public GameObject[] prop;

    public GameObject[] puzzleStartNode;
    public GameObject[] puzzleEndNode;
    public GameObject[] clueNode;
    public GameObject[] propNode;
}

public Item[] Stages;

// Start is called before the first frame update
public void ObjectActivation(string stageActivation)
{
    //stageOne
    if (stageActivation == "StageOne")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].clue.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].clue[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].puzzle.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].puzzle[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].prop.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].prop[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].puzzleStartNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].puzzleStartNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].puzzleEndNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].puzzleEndNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].clueNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].clueNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].propNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].propNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
        }
    }

    //stageTwo
    if (stageActivation == "StageTwo")
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].clue.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].clue[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].puzzle.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].puzzle[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].prop.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].prop[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].puzzleStartNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].puzzleStartNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].puzzleEndNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].puzzleEndNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].clueNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].clueNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Stages[1].propNode.Length; i++)
        {
            Stages[1].propNode[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could "teach" your items/stages how to do all the activation and deactivation stuff and then simply say `stage[0].Deactivate(); stage[1].Activate();`. Other than that, I dont really get a picture of how your game is supposed to work ^^ Is that all within one level? If not scenes might help you aswell ...

Comment: @yes Yes, both of stages of Puzzles is within one level. The reason is in the future, I would only want to disable certain components of puzzles and enable certain component. For example, Puzzle A is completed, then I would like to remove the Collider of Puzzle A and keep the Rigidbody then enable the Particle Effect that attached to it. I can do it by disabling and enabling each puzzle individually. But what if I am adding more Puzzles in the future. Like is there a way to make any puzzle, clue or prop that pass through this function will stay deactivate or activate.

Comment: @yes I have also tried the stage[0].Deactivate(); stage[1].Activate(); method but to no avail, may I know how to make arrays access a function?

Comment: Depends on what Type your arrays are.

Comment: @Draco18s Take my code as an example, may I know how to make array class access a function? such as Stage[0] and stage[1] without accessing the gameobject arrays inside the class?

Comment: `GameObject[] stages = ...` -> `stages[0].GetComponent<Transform>()` What methods (functions) you have access to depends on the Type of the array. Your `Stages` array is of Type `Item`, but I have no idea what methods it has avaialble because you didn't include that code. If your `Item` class does not have a `Deactivate` function you can't call it.

Comment: @Draco18s Oh! Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant with "teach the item class what it means to activate" was the following. In your Item class add the method `SetActive(bool)` and let it handle  activation/deactivation.

```
//I'd call it Stage, or the stages field below items for consistency
//but I took your names :D
public class Item
{
    //It's kinda better to store the right thing right away
    //unless ofc you need the GameObject reference for something you didnt mention
    public BoxCollider[] puzzles; 
    public BoxCollider[] clues;
    // ... and so on

    public void SetActive(bool activate) {
        foreach(var puzzle in puzzles) {
            puzzle.enabled = activate;
        }
        foreach(var clue in clues) {
            clue.enabled = activate;
        }
        // ... same for the other stuff
        // Basically, everything that has to do with activation/deactivation
        // of the stage goes in here
    }
}
```

When you want to activate/deactivate the stage you can now simply do

```
public Item[] stages;

public void ObjectActivation(string stageActivation) //I'd use an int tho, see below
{
    //stageOne
    if (stageActivation == "StageOne") {
        stages[0].SetActive(true);
        stages[1].SetActive(false);
    }
    // ...
}
```

To expand on the comment that I would use int and not string as argument, you could do the following with it

```
public Item[] stages;

//Arrays are zero indexed, so "StageOne" would actually be id 0
public void ActivateOneStageAndDeactivateTheRest(int stageId) {
    for(int i = 0; i < stages.Length; i++) {
        stages[i].SetActive(i == stageId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I didn't know you can compare values inside a round bracket! stages[i].SetActive(i == stageId). I was figuring out how to include function inside a nested class, it turns out very simple. Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: May I know why choose to passing int rather than string?

Comment: look at the last method - like the name suggest, you could enable one stage and disable all the others with just 2 lines of code.

Comment: Also you can do everything that equates to or returns the correct type (in this case bool) in parenthesis and even square brackets. What is important is the result. Its basically the same as `bool result = i == stageId;` and using that. You should care about readabilty tho, dont fabricate endless lines of code this way (i know its tempting to squeeze everything in one line) ;)

Comment: And a nested class is the same as any other class, only the scope is different (means how it can be, or rather has to be, refered to)